# Redirecting subdomain to its sub folder, Safari showing too many redirect occured trying to open

Tags: php, redirect, apache2, debian

[Possible Duplicate](http://How%20to%20redirect%20from%20a%20subdomain%20to%20a%20subfolder%20using%20.htaccess)

I did the same. But instead of using `.htaccess` I put these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.domain\.com  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301]
```

to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All          // I even changed None to All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All          // I even changed None to All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.domain\.com  
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting apache2, When I browse `one.domain.com` , Mozzila, IE Chrome not responding, But safari gives error

[image: Safari Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a 301 you're telling the browser to redirect to one.domain.com/folder which still passes your host condition.  Meaning on redirect 2 you're on page one.domain.com/folder/folder

Comment: It's done. I removed it. And its working like Expected.